# Convert PHP function to linux bash?

Tags: php, bash, shell, sh

I have a php function that generates a rollingkey for a webAPI to download a xml file,
this is literally the only reason i have PHP installed on my server and if it could be converted to bash id be able to uninstall php, could anyone assist?

```
<?php
function generateKey(String $password) 
{
$date = time();
$key = ( date( 'd', $date ) * 2 ) + ( date( 'm', $date) * 100 * 3 ) + ( date( 'y', $date ) * 10000 * 17 );
return md5( $key . $password );
}

print generateKey('abcd1234');
```

Comment: If you have php on the linux system you can run the php right in the terminal. Just type `php filename.php` but you'd have to replace the "print" with "echo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
generatekey() {
    local password=$1
    local d=$(date +%d)
    local m=$(date +%m)
    local y=$(date +%y)
    local key=$(( ${d#0} * 2 + ${m#0} * 100 * 3 + ${y#0} * 10000 * 17 ))
    echo -n "${key}${password}" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1
}

generatekey 'abcd1234'
```

Output:

```
f7e2b8ce423a63323f7b28271f052753
# As of Nov. 12, 2019
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is perfect, now i no longer require php on my tiny cloud VPS!  Thank you!

Comment: @user2879090 I have had a mistake in my answer. The command fails on specific days
which contains "08" or "09" field such as 8th day, 9th day, or Aug., Sep. 
due to the leading zero. Would you please update your copy with my
last answer? Sorry for the inconvenience. BR.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generatekey {
  Y=`date +%y`
  M=`date +%m`
  D=`date +%d`
  key=$(( 2 * D + 300 * M + 170000 * Y ))
  echo -n $key$1 | md5sum
}
```

Output:

```
$ generatekey 'abcd1234'
f7e2b8ce423a63323f7b28271f052753
```

Comment: You don't want that `.` in there. Or the newline that plain `echo` inserts.